# Why the value of initial spin angle ψ[0] in Eulerian dynamic equations cannot be 0

Tags: differential-equations

I am working out an Euler gyroscope according to the method in the textbook. In the case of $I11 = I22$, I think the trajectory of the gyroscope is mainly affected by the initial spin velocity , and the value of the initial spin angle should not affect the final result.

However, I find that if the initial value of `ψ[0]` is a non-zero real number(For example, `ψ[0]`=0.001), the numerical solution can be obtained. But if the initial value of `ψ[0]` is 0, an error will be reported:

```
EulerMatrix[{Pi/6, Pi/6, Pi/10}, {3, 1, 3}].{0, 0, 1}
M1 = 0; M2 = 0; M3 = 0;
I11 = 1; I22 = 1; I33 = 1;
s = NDSolve[{{{ω1[t]}, {ω2[t]}, {ω3[
       t]}} == {{Sin[θ[t]] Sin[ψ[t]], Cos[ψ[t]], 
       0}, {Sin[θ[t]] Cos[ψ[t]], -Sin[ψ[t]], 
       0}, {Cos[θ[t]], 0, 
       1}}.{{φ'[t]}, {θ'[t]}, {ψ'[
        t]}}(*Euler kinematics equations*), {{I11 ω1'[
         t]}, {I22 ω2'[t]}, {I33 ω3'[
         t]}} + {{(I33 - I22) ω2[t] ω3[
         t]}, {(I11 - I33) ω1[t] ω3[
         t]}, {(I22 - I11) ω1[t] ω2[
         t]}}   == {{M1}, {M2}, {M3}}(*Euler dynamics equations*), \
φ'[0] == 
    0.5(*Initial precession angular velocity*), θ'[0] == 
    0.(*Initial nutation angular velocity*), ψ'[0] == 
    0.2(*Initial spin velocity*), φ[0] == 
    Pi/6(*Initial precession angle*), θ[0] == 
    Pi/6(*Initial nutation angle*), ψ[0] == 
    0.0(*Initial spin angle*)}, {ω1, ω2, ω3, \
φ, θ, ψ}, {t, 0, 100}]
Plot[{θ[t], φ[t], ψ[t]} /. s, {t, 0, 30}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
Show[SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 3 Pi/2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2], Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None], 
 ParametricPlot3D[(EulerMatrix[{ φ[t], θ[t], ψ[
        t]}, {3, 1, 3}].{0, 0, 1}) /. s, {t, 0, 30}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, 
 ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi/2, 2}, ViewCenter -> Automatic]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structuring the script we have

```
M1 = 0; M2 = 0; M3 = 0;
I11 = 1; I22 = 1; I33 = 1;
II = DiagonalMatrix[{I11, I22, I33}];
MM = {M1, M2, M3};
R = {{Sin[θ[t]] Sin[ψ[t]], Cos[ψ[t]], 0}, {Sin[θ[t]] Cos[ψ[t]], -Sin[ψ[t]], 0}, {Cos[θ[t]], 0, 1}};
Ω = {ω1[t], ω2[t], ω3[t]};
ang = {φ[t], θ[t], ψ[t]};
vars = Join[Ω, ang];
kinematics = Thread[Ω == R.D[ang, t]];
sol = FullSimplify[Solve[kinematics, D[ang, t]][[1]]];
kinematica = sol /. {Rule -> Equal}; 
dynamics = Thread[II.D[Ω, t] + Cross[Ω,II.Ω] == MM];
movement = Join[kinematica, dynamics];
cinits = {ω1[0] == 0.5, ω2[0] == 0, ω3[0] == 0.2,φ[0] == Pi/6, θ[0] == Pi/6, ψ[0] == 0};
s = NDSolve[Join[movement, cinits], vars, {t, 0, 100}];

Plot[{θ[t], φ[t], ψ[t]} /. s, {t, 0, 30}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
Show[SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 3 Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2], Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None], 
ParametricPlot3D[(EulerMatrix[{φ[t], θ[t], ψ[t]}, {3, 1, 3}].{0, 0, 1}) /. s, {t, 0, 30}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi/2, 2}, ViewCenter -> Automatic]
```

NOTE

The error message can be eliminated by solving for $(\varphi'(t),\theta'(t),\phi'(t))$ the kinematic equations as is done thru the commands **sol, kinematica** in the script.

Answer (score 0):

**This may be a bug.**

When I exchange the matrix writing order of Euler kinematics equations, this error disappears magically, although this change does not change the meaning of matrix equation.

```
EulerMatrix[{Pi/6, Pi/6, Pi/10}, {3, 1, 3}].{0, 0, 1}
M1 = 0; M2 = 0; M3 = 0;
I11 = 1; I22 = 1; I33 = 1;
s = NDSolve[{{{Sin[θ[t]] Sin[ψ[t]], Cos[ψ[t]], 
       0}, {Sin[θ[t]] Cos[ψ[t]], -Sin[ψ[t]], 
       0}, {Cos[θ[t]], 0, 
       1}}.{{φ'[t]}, {θ'[t]}, {ψ'[
        t]}} == {{ω1[t]}, {ω2[t]}, {ω3[
       t]}}(*Euler kinematics equations*), {{I11 ω1'[
         t]}, {I22 ω2'[t]}, {I33 ω3'[
         t]}} + {{(I33 - I22) ω2[t] ω3[
         t]}, {(I11 - I33) ω1[t] ω3[
         t]}, {(I22 - I11) ω1[t] ω2[
         t]}} == {{M1}, {M2}, {M3}}(*Euler dynamics equations*), \
φ'[0] == 
    0.5(*Initial precession angular velocity*), θ'[0] == 
    0.(*Initial nutation angular velocity*), ψ'[0] == 
    0.2(*Initial spin velocity*), φ[0] == 
    Pi/6(*Initial precession angle*), θ[0] == 
    Pi/6(*Initial nutation angle*), ψ[0] == 
    0.0(*Initial spin angle*)}, {ω1, ω2, ω3, \
φ, θ, ψ}, {t, 0, 100}]
Plot[{θ[t], φ[t], ψ[t]} /. s, {t, 0, 30}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
Show[SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 3 Pi/2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2], Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None], 
 ParametricPlot3D[(EulerMatrix[{φ[t], θ[t], ψ[
        t]}, {3, 1, 3}].{0, 0, 1}) /. s, {t, 0, 30}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, 
 ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi/2, 2}, ViewCenter -> Automatic]
```

So I think it is probably an internal bug of Mathematica, and I hope other people in this community can notice this bug and explain it further.